# IPad screen flickers when jquery mobile li element expands

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have created a jquery mobile list. On every `<li>` element I have a button, onclick of which it shows a div with dynamic content and expands `<li>`. On click of that button again, that div hides and `<li>` regains it size.
This works very well on Android devices, but on IPad when that `<li>` expands the transition looks very ugly nad flickering. 
Is there any way to expand that `<li>` smoothly in IPad.

I also tried observing it using google's ADB extension, but I observed that height of `<li>` didnt change even when it expanded.
Is it jquery mobile's default `<li>` behavior?

Comment: <style>
    /*** patch for jquerymobile page flicker that was appending ***/       
  .ui-page {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }        
</style>

Comment: its not a real solution but try to reduce the transition time

Answer (score 0):

Implement fastclick.js found here: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.

Link the .js to your document.

Simply add

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    });
</script>
```

to the head of your document.

No more flash/flicker when using any sort of transition, be that a page transition or li elements.